# How can angularjs ui-router controller read parameter from a java backend redirect?

Tags: java, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Route definition as follow：

```
.state('about', {
            url: '/about',
            controller: 'AboutCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'views/about/about.html'
        })
```

Java backend:

```
servletResponse.setHeader("type", "something");
servletResponse.sendRedirect("http://xxxxx/yyyy/#!/about");
```

So how can I get parameter of "type" in AboutCtrl ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about how to use `servletResponse`, but from the `setHeader` method's name, you are trying to set a header value, not a parameter value.

There are couple of ways you can resolve a parameter with `ui-router` (i'm assuming you are using `ui-router`). You can check this [link](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing) for more details on that, but here are some ways:

If you decide to go with `servletResponse.sendRedirect("http://xxxxx/yyyy/#!/about/something");`, you can do something like this:

```
.state('about', {
   url: '/about/:type', //or even url: '/about/{type}'
   controller: 'AboutCtrl',
   templateUrl: 'views/about/about.html'
});

function AboutCtrl($stateParams){
   console.log($stateParams.type); //something
}
```

If you want to use query parameters `servletResponse.sendRedirect("http://xxxxx/yyyy/#!/about?type=something");`, you should match your state's URL with `url: '/about?type'`.

If you want to use parameters without defining them in your state's `url`, you can do something like this:

```
.state('about', {
   url: '/about/',
   params: {
        type: null
    },
   controller: 'AboutCtrl',
   templateUrl: 'views/about/about.html'
});

function AboutCtrl($stateParams){
   console.log($stateParams.type); //something
}
```

You can find more details and variations in the provided link.

Comment: Following worked for me: 
`servletResponse.sendRedirect("http://xxxxx/yyyy/#!/about/something");`
and corresponding code for $stateProvider
whereas `servletResponse.sendRedirect("http://xxxxx/yyyy/#!/about?type=something");`
gave me type=null, and did not set the value that was passed.

Comment: My mistake, that particular case should be matched with `url: '/about?type'`. I will edit this right away.